# What does this xargs command do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

I'm very new to xargs and can't seem to understand what this command does. Specifically I get confused with the `find` part of it and the brackets. Any explanations are welcome.

```
xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -type d \( -perm -0002 -a ! -perm -1000 \)
```

Comment: read the [xargs manual pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xargs.1.html)

Comment: @Jdamian that is where I started

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of this can be found in the xargs and find man pages

---

```
xargs -I '{}'
```

Is replace string, and will replace any occurrence of '{}' with the line from the input to xargs

---

```
find '{}'
```

Search the directory with the name held in '{}'

---

```
-xdev
```

Don't go to other filesytstems

---

```
-type d
```

Only search for directories

---

```
\(
```

Not 100% but i think these are just to group the last 2 args

---

```
-perm -0002 -a ! -perm -1000
```

Check permission contain 0002 and not 1000

`-a` is and
`!` is not

Look up permission bits if you are unsure what these represent.

---